# Halt a recursively called function

Tags: python, recursion

I'm trying to halt the for loop below once values `(x,y)` or `(z,2)` have been returned so that the value `i` doesn't keep increasing, and simply halts when the `if` or `elif` condition is first

```
def maxPalindrome(theList):
    # students need to put some logic here
    maxcomplist = theList[:]
    maxcomplist.reverse()
    control = len(theList) - 1
    # exit if maxPalindrome is True
    for i in range(control):
        if maxcomplist[:] == theList[:]:
            x = 0
            y = len(theList)
            return (x, y)
            break
        elif maxcomplist[i:control] == theList[i:control]:
            successList = theList[i:control]
            z = i
            w = len(theList) - z - 1
            return (z, w)
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Instead of trying to figure out how to "halt" the recursive execution, I might suggest you check out the Wikipedia page on [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion). More specifically, read about the **base case** because that is how you stop recursive execution.

Comment: Not strictly an answer, but when you're getting started, some recursive functions can be very hard to get your head around. Consider picking up a book like the Little Schemer (http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/BTLS/) that teaches you strategies for dividing problems up in a fashion more suitable for recursion.

Comment: this doesn't look like a recursive function at all. It doesn't call it self anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote in a comment already: that function isn't a recursive one at all.
Recursion means, that a function calls itself to complete it's purpose. This call can be indirect, meaning that the function uses helper function that will call the first function again.
But your code doesn't cover both cases.

A recursive function always have a certain architecture:

- the first thing after being called should be to test, if the primitive case (or one primitive case among options) has been reached. if so, it returns.
- If not it will compute whatever is needed and pass this results to itself again, 
  untill the primitive case is reached, and the nested function calls will finish in one after the other.

One well-known usage of recursion is the [quicksort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) algorithm:

```
def quicksort(alist):
    if len(alist) < 2: 
        return alist # primitive case: a list of size one is ordered

    pivotelement = alist.pop()
    # compute the 2 lists for the next recursive call
    left  = [element for element in alist if element < pivotelement]#left = smaller than pivotelemet
    right = [element for element in alist if element >= pivotelement]#left = greater than pivotelemet

    # call function recursively
    return quicksort(left) + [pivotelement] + quicksort(right)
```

So the "stop" must be the return of a primitive case. This is vital for recursion. You cannot just break out somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the question - if I get it right, that what you want already happens. If you `return`, the function stops running.

Some comments in addition to this answer:

- As well, I cannot see where the function is called recursively, nor what

  ```
  exit if maxPalindrome is True
  ```

  means. (Is this a comment, maybe?)
- Besides, the `maxcomplist[:]==theList[:]` does not make much sense to me, and seem to be a waste of time and memory, and to have this comparison in each iteration loop doesn't make it faster as well.